# Save previous bar values when using a loop in pine script

Tags: arrays, function, loops, pine-script

In pine script I'm calling a function that sums the previous bar value with an increment:

```
myFunction(myVar1) =>
    var int myVar2 = 0
    myVar2 := myVar1 + nz(myVar2[1],1)
```

The increment value is added using a loop that calls the function and the result is stored in an array:

```
myArray = array.new_int(0)

var int myVar1 = 1
myVar1 := 1

while myVar1 <= 3
    array.push(myArray, myFunction(myVar1))
    myVar1 += 1
```

The result in the **first bar** was expected. Since there is no previous bar the previous value is replaced by 1 `nz(myVar2[1],1)`

```
plot(myArray.get(myArray, 0))
plot(myArray.get(myArray, 1))
plot(myArray.get(myArray, 2))

Result: [2, 3, 4]
```

But in the **second bar**:

```
Result: [5, 6, 7]
My expected result: [3, 5, 7]
```

Since it runs the loop for the **first bar** first and then runs the loop again in the **second bar** it uses for **myVar2[1]** the last value **4** saved when running the last loop in the **first bar**.

How can the previous bar values be stored correctly when using a loop so that the expected results can be achieved:

```
First bar: [2, 3, 4]
Second bar: [3, 5, 7]
Third bar: [4, 7, 10]
```

Comment: On the second bar, `myVar2[1]` will contain 4 with each pass through your loop, because it looks at the value it had on the previous bar (first bar), which is 4 and doesn't change. So the `[5,6,7]` you're getting is logical. Not sure how you would achieve your expected result, nor do I understand the logic behind that expected result.

Comment: To simplify with the example above while in the **second bar** how can I get the values **2**, **3** and **4** from the **first bar**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70346758/save-previous-bar-values-when-using-a-loop-in-pine-script?noredirect=1#comment124359160_70346758): You could save the current array in another array. That way, you always have access to the array values of the previous bar.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My Script", overlay=false)

var int     myVar1    = na
var int[]   myArray   = array.new_int(3) // Current array
var int[]   prevArray = array.new_int(3) // Previous array

myFunction(myVar1) =>
    var int myVar2 = 0
    myVar2 := myVar1 + nz(myVar2[1],1)
    
myVar1 := 1

prevArray := array.copy(myArray) // Save current array
array.clear(myArray)             // Clear current array

while myVar1 <= 3
    array.push(myArray, myFunction(myVar1))
    myVar1 += 1

// Show previous array
plot(array.get(prevArray, 0), 'prevArray[0]')
plot(array.get(prevArray, 1), 'prevArray[1]')
plot(array.get(prevArray, 2), 'prevArray[2]')

// Show current array
plot(array.get(myArray, 0), 'myArray[0]')
plot(array.get(myArray, 1), 'myArray[1]')
plot(array.get(myArray, 2), 'myArray[2]')
```